# Sinatra Session

Tags: ruby, session, websocket, sinatra

```
get '/' do
if !request.websocket?
  erb :index
else
request.websocket do |ws|
  ws.onopen do
     content_type :json  
    u = User.first(:username => session[:username])   
      ws.send({:msg => "start", :player_id => u.id.to_s,})

    settings.sockets << ws
  end
  ws.onmessage do |msg|
    EM.next_tick { settings.sockets.each{|s| s.send(msg) } }
  end
  ws.onclose do
    warn("websocket closed")
    settings.sockets.delete(ws)
  end
end
end
end
```

In my web-socket handshake I can't seem to get the user session to work.Sessions work everywhere but during a web-socket request. It comes up empty every time.

In my app the session setup.

```
enable :sessions
set(:session_fail, '/login')
set(:session_secret, 'secretsession')
```

Comment: this isn't really a solution, but I've found that [rack-flash](https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash) can be used for session. The flash key-vals are by default saved for a single request only, but you can make it persistent by setting the key to its existing value on each request.

Comment: Have you tried using Rack::Session::Cookie? Example here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions . That should help you.